# Logger does not receive messages from modules it called when instantiated elsewhere to `__main__`?

Tags: python, logging, module

I have three command line interface based programs, they all take a similar form:

```
import sys
from Foo import Foo
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('SPECIAL_NAME')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    std_out_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    std_out_handler.setFormatter(MyStdOutFormatter())
    file_out_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path)
    file_out_handler.setFormatter(MyLogFileFormatter())
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, handlers = [std_out_handler, file_out_handler])
    
    f = Foo()
    f.DoFoo()
    logger.info('Done.')
```

Further, each CLI program calls various modules which take similar form:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Foo:
    def DoFoo(self):
        logger.info('Done doing Foo')
```

When I run any of these CLI programs I receive log message to both handlers akin to

```
[Foo] Done doing Foo
[CLI] Done.
```

That is, the logger with the name `SPECIAL_NAME` captures the log messages of the modules it calls, its child logs. This all works perfectly.

---

I have created a PyQt5 based UI which makes use of the 3 CLI programs (they interact in some form). The UI performs some of the tasks in each CLI's `__main__` such as loading parameters file and building some objects. Once completed the UI starts a separate `Thread` for each CLI. After creating and starting the threads the UI gets the loggers from each CLI based on their `SPECIAL_NAME`.

```
cli1 = logging.getLogger('SPECIAL_NAME_1')
cli2 = logging.getLogger('SPECIAL_NAME_2')
cli3 = logging.getLogger('SPECIAL_NAME_3')
```

It adds a new handler to these loggers (which do not have the `stdout` and file handlers because their respective `__main__` were not called) which redirects log messages to `QTextEdit` fields using PyQt signals/slots to display the CLI logging information in the UI.

---

My issue is that only the "CLI level" log messages seem to be getting through. For example instead of seeing the log

```
[Foo] Done doing Foo
[CLI] Done.
```

I only see

```
[CLI] Done.
```

**How can I setup the loggers so that the log messages from the CLI called modules appear?**

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any code relating to your PyQt5 setup, so I can't be sure, but it might be that you haven't set a logger level somewhere. The default level is `WARNING`, so you wouldn't see any `DEBUG` or `INFO` messages. In the actual CLI code called from `if __name__ == '__main__':`, the `basicConfig()` call sets the level to `INFO` for the root logger, which is inherited by descendant loggers. Try calling `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)` and see if the messages appear.